# In a template, how do I bind to a deeply nested property of an object delivered by an observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-template, angular2-observables

I have an object that I get via an observable called `compModel`. It gives me a large configuration object that I need to use to adjust pieces of dom. One of the things I want to do is make some checkboxes be checked/unchecked according to this model, but I can't access their respective properties.

1. Evaluates the compModel observable as truthy and checks the box **when data is received.**

`<input type="checkbox" checked="{{compModel | async}}">`

2. When obj is defined on the compModel **eventually** this evaluates to `null` and the box is not checked at any point. I think this is interpreted as passing the `obj` property of an observable to the async pipe, which returns null because the observable itself doesn't have `obj`, the future data does.

`<input type="checkbox" checked="{{compModel.obj | async}}">`

3. I get an error saying that angular `Cannot read property boolean of undefined`. The boolean value here is what I'm after. How do I get it?

`<input type="checkbox" checked="{{compModel.obj.boolean | async}}">`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="{{(compModel | async)?.obj?.boolean}}">
```

You need to pipe the actual observable with async and then conditionally access it's future properties using the elvis operator to handle the case where they're not available yet.

Comment: You're a beautiful person.

Comment: :D no problem! That one had me hung up for a bit when I first started working with binding to observables as well